# como pegar a data do servidor com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou tentando pegar a data do servidor, sei que da para pegar a data do servidor com php, mais será possível com JQuery?

Comment: faz um ajax para um arquivo php que retorne a data do server

Comment: Você quer pegar a data de um servidor específico? Ou quer apenas garantir a data correta? Já que pode pegar a data também de um serviço web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas com Jquery não é possível obter a data do servidor.
Visto que Jquery é um framework javascript onde o mesmo é executado apenas no navegador do usuário.

Comment: ele tem no server-side o PHP

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Sim ele tem php no server, porém a pergunta foi: Como pegar a data usando somente com Jquery.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta JahnKrauss.

Comment: hum...ok, mas ainda assim a sua resposta não esta 100% correta porque induz o AP a pensar que javascript é impedido de fazer essa tarefa e o NodeJs resolveria o problema ficandando tudo em javascript

Answer (score -1):

É possivel assim, coloque esse codigo no javascript na pagina:

`var variavelDataJquery = "<?=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');?>";`

Comment: desse jeito a data que esta pegando é a computador cliente não do server

Comment: Não, não é amigo... Se vc reparar a função `date` do PHP retorna a data do servidor.

Comment: hum... verdade ta ali a a tag **<?** do php, só que assim descaracterizou a primícia do AP que deseja fazer isso em javascript, mas é sim uma resposta 50% javascript e 50% php rsrsrs

Comment: kkkk, é verdade...